# YAWS fronting Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, erlang, yaws

Is there currently any easy way to set up a YAWS web server in front of Apache Tomcat Servlet container, similar to popular Apache httpd + Tomcat set up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe there is an AJP connector for YAWS, but you should be able to front Tomcat with YAWS via HTTP. YAWS is relatively easy to setup as a reverse proxy. See the man page here for details (see **revproxy**):

http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf

**Note:** This is not yet considered production quality so you will want to do plenty of testing to ensure this satisfies your production requirements.

I do not know what your use case is, but you may find [Nginx](http://nginx.net/) is a worthwhile alternative to Apache as a load-balanced, HTTP reverse proxy in front of Tomcat. There are a number of good tutorials for this on the web, or checkout the recent Linux Journal article (requires a subscription):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10108

Comment: David. Thanks for the answer. I do not have a particular use case, but thought since YAWS is written in Erlang it might perform/scale better than Apache under heavy load

Comment: Be mindful that your largest bottleneck will be the deciding factor in your ability to scale. More often than not your HTTP server is not the scale limiter, it is your database, application server or poorly optimized code.